# $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$, where $N$ is normal in $G$ and $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, definition, sylow-theory

In 'A Course in Group Theory' by Humphreys, Proposition 11.14 says that if $G$ is a finite group, $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$.

But doesn't this fail in the case where $P \cap N = \{1\}$? I thought the definition of a Sylow $p$-subgroup excludes $\lbrace1 \rbrace$, since the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup requires an order $p^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer (i.e. not zero). If not, we need to adjust the definition of Sylow $p$-subgroup to a subgroup of order $p^n$ where $n$ is non-negative. However I don't think Humphreys intends this, as in his answer to exercise 11.3 he uses $\{1\}$ as an example of a group that is not a Sylow 2-subgroup.

As an example: I think we could have $G = D_3$ (the dihedral group with 6 elements), $N = \langle a \rangle$ where $a$ is a rotation, and $P = \langle b \rangle$ where $b$ is a reflection. Then $P \cap N = \{1\}$, which is not a Sylow 2-subgroup of $N$ although $N$ is normal in $G$ and $P$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup. Please let me know what you think. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bit unsatisfying, but the answer is that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ for which $|G|$ is not divisible by $p$ is simply the identity.  Note that $1$ is indeed a power of $p$ for any prime $p$, so if $p^0=1$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$, then $\{1\}$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup.  So, $P\cap N=1$ is not a contradition because $P$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $D_3$ and $\{1\}$ is, in fact, the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $\langle a \rangle \cong C_3$.  (For an even easier example, consider $\mathbb{Z}_6$.)

If the book doesn't define this way, it's possible that the writer just forgot to write an exception to this Proposition.  This is standard in group theory literature.

Comment: Nice to know I'm not seeing things! Is it really a non-standard definition though? For example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_p-subgroup#Sylow_theorems) has a page on the Sylow theorems which also states $n>0$.

Comment: @user50229 Actually, note that this definition only applies to groups *of order* $p^nm$, where $n>0$ and $(p,m)=1$.  Does the book simply fail to give a definition of the Sylow $p$-subgroup of groups whose order is not divisible by $p$?

Comment: Note that the statement of the first Sylow theorem does not prohibit $p^k=1$.

Comment: You could be right there, I don't recall that it does give a definition in the case where $p$ does not divide the order of $G$.